# The integral of a discontinunous function is not absolutely continuous function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

We know that even if a function $f(x)$ is not a continuous function of $x$, it's integral $\int_{-\infty}^x f(s)ds$ can still be a continuous function of $x$. I have a question: how horrible (in terms of discontinuity) of $f(x)$ need to be, in order to make $\int_{-\infty}^x f(s)ds$ a non-absolutely continuous function of $x$? a non-continuous function of $x$? Assume that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

The background of this question is the following: 
I am solving an ODE with discontinuous RHS,  e.g., $\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$, where $f$ is a discontinuous function of $x$. There is an solution concept called "Filippov Solution", which says: at each discontinuous point $x$ of $f$, we consider an open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\delta$, denoted by $B(x,\delta)$, then we collect the value of $f$ on that open ball, denoted by $f(B(x,\delta))$, then we take the closed convex hull of $f(B(x,\delta))$, denoted by $\overline{co}\{f(B(x,\delta))\}$, then we shrink the radius to 0, denoted by $\bigcap_{\delta>0}\overline{co}\{f(B(x,\delta))\}$. Then the Filippov solution of the ODE $\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$ is an absolutely continuous function $x(t)$ such that $\dot{x}(t)\in\bigcap_{\delta>0}\overline{co}\{f(B(x,\delta))\}$ for almost all $t$.

As you can see from this solution concept, although you have the room to pick a vector in $\bigcap_{\delta>0}\overline{co}\{f(B(x,\delta))\}$ when you encounter a discontinuous point of $f$, you cannot just pick an arbitrary vector in $\bigcap_{\delta>0}\overline{co}\{f(B(x,\delta))\}$. This is because, intuitively, if you pick the vector too wildly, then the state of the system may evolve to another discontinuous point and if you again pick a wild vector and you do it too much, then you might not be able to eventually find an absolutely continuous function $x(t)$. I think should be some quantitative method to help me pick the vector in $\bigcap_{\delta>0}\overline{co}\{f(B(x,\delta))\}$ when I encounter a discontinuous point of $f$ so that I could eventually get an absolutely continuous function $x(t)$. My intuition is that once I encountered a discontinuous point, I should try to pick a vector, such that it will lead the state of the system to a direction that is still continuous for $f$, i.e., seek a path ($x(t)$) that tries to avoid discontinuous point of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the (Lebesgue) integral to exist at all, $f$ must be in $L^1(-\infty, x)$, and then the integral is absolutely continuous.  To get a discontinuous (but finite) integral, you need a distribution rather than an ordinary function.

Comment: +1. To add an example, the distributional derivative of the Cantor function is not an $L^1$ function. It is a nonzero distribution concentrated on the Cantor set. Yet all $L^1$ functions concentrated on the Cantor set are zero.